# DirectX subtract one mesh from another

Tags: c++, directx

I am working on DirectX code which subtracts one mesh from another. My idea was to use TriangleTests::Intersect function from <DirectXCollision.h> and check if the result is greater than the vector length of the vertex which I use to cast ray (and if it does I clamp length to result). This way vertices are kind of "pushed away" by the second mesh . However, it doesn't work and I really don't understand why.

```
    {
        XMFLOAT3 centroid = Centroid();
        XMVECTOR vCentroid = XMLoadFloat3(&centroid);
        float result, length;
        for (auto& v : vertices)
        {
            XMVECTOR vPoint = XMLoadFloat4(&v.position);
            for (int i = 0; i < shape.indices.size(); i += 3)
            {
                int index0 = shape.indices[i];
                int index1 = shape.indices[i + 1];
                int index2 = shape.indices[i + 2];

                if (TriangleTests::Intersects(
                    vCentroid,
                    XMVector3Normalize(vPoint),
                    XMLoadFloat4(&shape.vertices[index0].position),
                    XMLoadFloat4(&shape.vertices[index1].position),
                    XMLoadFloat4(&shape.vertices[index2].position),
                    result)
                    )
                {
                    XMStoreFloat(&length, XMVector3Length(vPoint));
                    if (length > result)
                    {
                        XMStoreFloat4(
                            &v.position,
                            XMVector3ClampLength(vPoint, result, result)
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
DirectX::XMFLOAT3 BaseMesh::Centroid()
    {
        float x, y, z;
        x = y = z = 0.0f;
        for (const auto& v : vertices)
        {
            x += v.position.x;
            y += v.position.y;
            z += v.position.z;
        }
        return { x / vertices.size(), y / vertices.size(),z / vertices.size() };
    }
```

Comment: This is the concept of 'collision response' in game physics. You can find a number of books and articles on the topic online.